# The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server

Tags: lamp

I installed LAMP on ubuntu all its OK showing just like the tutorial. but last day I made a databases and edit password all become error, phpmyadmin cant access so I'm try to reinstall for 3 times but still like the picture. I'm so try inset text on apache2.conf but still error please help me

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How did you install it in the first place...?

Comment: First you have to remove it to re-install...

Comment: yes fix it sudo apt-get  mysql-server my last day the installing error but now all its ok thanks

Comment: It should have been: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. Glade it's fixed!

Comment: first installing im use sudo apt-get install "mysql-server mysql-common mysql-clien" mybe just common and clien has installed and mysql server error